# Spring @WebMvcTest ignores field "controllers"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-test

I'm trying to test my simple web application using `@WebMvcTest`. I have only 2 controllers `HomeController` and `PersonController` in my app. I want to instantiate only one controller in one test class. To do so, I use `controllers` field of the [`@WebMvcTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html) annotation. But it looks like this field is ignored and both controllers are instantiated. Because even when I specify only one controller in my test, request handler of other controller pass the test. Could you let me know, what's wrong here, please?

I work with
openjdk version "17.0.5"
springBoot version "3.0.4"
spring-boot-starter-test version "3.0.4"

There are 2 controllers, I omitted my configuration file.

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/home"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Model model) 
    }
}

@Controller
public class PersonController {

}
```

This is my test

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = {PersonController.class})//I specify to test empty PersonController
public class MyWebMvcTest {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void testHomeIsOk() throws Exception {
        mockMvc
                .perform(get("/home"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
        // still pass the test, allthough /home request is handled in HomeController 
    }
}
```